# Discriminative models Machine Learning

Tags: machine-learning

I'm a little bit confused about discriminative models.
I understood that a probabilistic classifier use the maximum likelihood to understand which class an input belongs to, while a linear classifier use a linear combination of the input to classify.
At this point I do not understand if discriminative models are probabilistic classifiers or linear classifiers.

Comment: @desertnaut how is machine learning theory not about programming?

Comment: It is not (edited back) - please see the suggested link (also @Liam) - ML questions here must be about *implementation*; if not, there are several other SE sites where such non-implementation questions are indeed on-topic (e. g. see [Generative vs. discriminative](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/12421/93018) at CV as already suggested).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A Discriminative model ‌models the decision boundary between the classes. A Generative Model ‌explicitly models the actual distribution of each class. In final both of them is predicting the conditional probability P(y | x).A Generative Model ‌learns the joint probability distribution p(x,y). It predicts the conditional probability with the help of Bayes Theorem.A Discriminative model ‌learns the conditional probability distribution p(y|x). Both of these models were generally used in supervised learning problems.

A more in-depth discussion can be found in the Cross Validated thread [Generative vs. discriminative](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/12421/generative-vs-discriminative).

Comment: Thank you for you clear answer. So why SVM is considered a discriminative model if it does not use probability? It is for the fact that it tries to separate the dataset defining the boundaries of classes like the concept of discriminative models?

Comment: @FrancescoPro you're welcome. I think [This](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/12421/generative-vs-discriminative#:~:text=SVMs%20and%20decision%20trees%20are,two%20classes%2C%20given%20a%20kernel.) can be useful for in depth concept that you are interested in.